# Why gradle's buildscript classpath doesn't contain buildSrc?

Tags: gradle

i can't see `buildSrc` on the buildscript classpath in gradle; i can access it...but it somehow isn't there

i expected that it's there...because the buildscript can use those classes

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript{
        dependencies{
                classpath gradleApi()
        }
}


task show(){
A.asd()
buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it }
}
```

contents of: buildSrc/src/main/java/A.java

```
public class A{
    public static void asd(){
        System.out.println(A.class + " is invokable from"+A.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    }
}
```

output:

```
:buildSrc:clean
...
:buildSrc:build
class A is invokable from/home/kirk/projects/bt/ews/tx3/buildSrc/build/classes/main/
/home/kirk/tools/gradle-1.11/lib/gradle-core-1.11.jar
...other nonrelated jars/etc
:show
```

Answer (score 2):

`buildscript { dependencies { classpath ... } }` is the way to explicitly add build script dependencies. The `buildSrc` output directory is added implicitly.

Comment: i know, but why `buildSrc` is not present in `buildscript.configurations.classpath`

Comment: for production it would work as expected, beacuse the plugin is on the classpath, but during development; when the plugin resides at `buildSrc`...i don't have it on `buildscript.classpath`

Comment: i wanted to put some custom javac processor onto the classpath, which was included in the plugin sources